# Read Java application file fom a Jar library contained in the same Java application

Tags: java, file, jar, external

I have created a Jar library which its initialization, capabilities, features, etc. should be customized. The problem is that I want this customization to be performed using an external XML file, so the Jar library reads that file and initializes accordingly. The scenario is the following:

I have a Java application which contains the Jar library and the config.xml file. How do I make the Jar library to read the config.xml file? An image for a better understanding:

[Diagram http://imageshack.us/a/img826/1888/readxmlfromjar.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img826/1888/readxmlfromjar.png)

I have been searching for hours but all I find is how to read files within the same jar file with the resources approach. Can this be done at all? If not, any good alternative out there?

Comment: How you solved this issue. I've similar issue, I made a maven library file but I need end user who use the library to customize it by adding information to .properties file in his own project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip utils from java.util.zip package http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Like here [Read a file inside a Zip archive and put its content into a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765439/read-a-file-inside-a-zip-archive-and-put-its-content-into-a-string-in-android)

Comment: I am not sure whether this question is about android since there is no android tag attached to the question

Comment: I don't want to read a file contained in a jar, I want to read an external file from a jar using relative pathing.

Comment: David, the blue rectangle in your diagram is a jar archive, right?
@bot: this code is the same on java se

Comment: @zacheusz Yup, when exported it will be an executable Jar.

Comment: So to read file from it you must use zip utils.
Obtaining the path is trivial.