# In Android, is it necessary to loop through all files/directories in a zip to read content from a file at known location?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, zip

I want to read first line of a file inside a zip file.
Now I do it using while loop like this one [sample stackoverflow quesion link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765439/read-a-file-inside-a-zip-archive-and-put-its-content-into-a-string-in-android)

But I know the exact location of file inside that zip. And the zip file is very big(can be more than 500mb).

So I'm thinking is there a way to read that file without looping through all files using while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ZipFile` instead of `ZipInputStream`. This reads the zip file's central directory (see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure)) and not the whole file. You can then use [`entries()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries%28%29) or [`getEntry(java.lang.String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29) and [`getInputStream(java.util.zip.ZipEntry)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29) to get an input stream for the entry:

```
String entryName = // put name of your entry here
File file = // put your zip file here
ZipFile zipFile = null;
try {
    zipFile = ZipFile(file);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(entryName);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
        // read stream here e.g. using BufferedReader
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception or delete catch block
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (zipFile != null) {
        zipFile.close();
    }
}
```